# Getting Error When passing value from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sending Value from controller to model but it shows error 
"
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'email'

Filename: models/Pmodel.php

Line Number: 58
"

This is the controller which sends the value

```
$user_email=$_GET['email'];
$this->load->model('Pmodel');

$data['email']=$this->Pmodel->profile_model($user_email);

$this->load->view('dashboard/profile',$data);
```

and now the model that acquire the values

```
public function profile_model($arr)
{
    $email=$arr->'email';

    print_r($email);

    $query=$this->db->where(['user_data.email'=>$email])
        ->from('user')
        ->join('user_data', 'user_data.email = user.email')
        ->get();    


    $q= $query->result_array(); 

    return $q;
}
```

When i Print_r($email) it shows error

Comment: first insert an id for joining table

Comment: i am not using 'id'. its email that is common in my table so i have to use email.

Comment: then you can use only one table.

Comment: I got the answer i just have to pass the value since its getting only single value thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to print_r($arr) only.

you can just directly use like this

`$query=$this->db->where(['user_data.email'=>$arr])
        ->from('user')
        ->join('user_data', 'user_data.email = user.email')
        ->get();`

Or,

`$email = $arr;`

`$query=$this->db->where(['user_data.email'=>$email])
        ->from('user')
        ->join('user_data', 'user_data.email = user.email')
        ->get();`

Comment: thanx your answer worked i was trying to pass it like an object but '$arr' was getting my value alone. so their was no need.

Answer (score 0):

$email=$arr->'email'

Maybe replace it with this:
$email=$arr['email']
Or
$email=$arr->email

Comment: no it did not work shows another error now     A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/Pmodel.php

Line Number: 58

Array ( ) array(0) { }